# gzip the existing json file in python 2.7

Tags: python, json, gzip

I want to zip the existing json file in python, but the below code giving error. 
is it because of python version ?

```
cat Comp.py

#!/usr/bin/python

import gzip
import os
import json

input = open("/home/jigu/Downloads/360.json", 'rb')
s = input.read()
input.close()

output = gzip.GzipFile("/home/jigu/Downloads/360.json.gz", 'wb')
output.write(s)
output.close()

print("done")
```

**Error**

```
$ ./Comp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Comp.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "/home/jigu/python/bin/gzip.py", line 11, in <module>
    import __builtin__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GzipFile'
```

**Python Version**

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into [docs of gzip module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) and if I am not mistaken your code should work, nonetheless [examples section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage) has code for gzip-ing existing code using `gzip.open`, which after taking paths from your code would be:

```
import gzip
import shutil
with open("/home/jigu/Downloads/360.json", 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open("/home/jigu/Downloads/360.json.gz", 'wb') as f_out:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Can you test if it does work for you?

As side note: you do not need to `import json` here, as you are neither parsing JSON or serializing python object to JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My apologies, this code is working fine now. I just noticed that the file gzip.pyc was exist at the same path (this is old file name of Comp.py) and I don't know how it got created. I removed the file and it worked as expected.